# IAR Failed to generate browse indexing file, paths are too long

Tags: iar

I'm observing these errors in Source Browser Log in IAR Embedded Workbench 9.20.1 when opening my project
Logs:
Source Browse Log created.
Launching source browser
The browse files cannot be generated at /../ , **paths are too long**. Please move the browse info folder.
**Failed to generate browse indexing file**.

Is there any solution for this problem, knowing that I don't had this error using older version of IAR.

Many Thanks!

This error appear when opening the project.
Fatal error while generating source browse information.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the rest of the tags also

Comment: Shorten the paths

Answer (score 2):

The *Source Browser* settings have changed in the later IDEs (v9+).

Earlier versions of the IDE had their *Source Browser* information stored in the "Object Output Directory" (`$OBJ_DIR$`, set in the `Project Options` →  `General Options` → `Output Directories` → `Object files`).

In general, this would mean (e.g., for the *Debug* configuration):

```
$PROJ_DIR$/Debug/Obj
```

In which any *argument variables* (`$xxxxx$`) would expand into the corresponding full path name.

In v9+ IDEs, the *Source Browser* output offers a specific setting for "Browse files" (defaults to "Debug/BrowseInfo") in the same project options page. Effectively, the setting will point to:

```
$PROJ_DIR$/Debug/BrowseInfo
```

This means that, the full path name resulting from the argument variable expansion also becomes longer and, depending on how deeply the project files are stored in the file system, might end up exceeding the maximum allowed resulting path length (~250 characters).

One workaround might be to use the User's temporary folder (`%TEMP%`) for storing these generated files. In order to express the Windows environment settings in the IDE, the variable must be expressed as `$_TEMP_$`.

One example for settting the "Browse files" field (Originally `Debug\BrowseInfo`):

```
$_TEMP_$\$PROJ_FNAME$\$CONFIG_NAME$\BrowseInfo
```

Or any other variation that would make sense for keeping the resulting full path from exceeding the operating system's limitations.

After changing the parameter, `Project` → `Clean Browse Info` can discard the previous information and recreate the index.

More on the IDE's *Argument Variables* can be found [here](https://netstorage.iar.com/FileStore/STANDARD/001/001/665/arm/doc/EWARM_IDEGuide.ENU.pdf#page=89).

Answer (score 0):

I also currently faced an issue with Browser information that never stopped and it was related with a "&" on a project folder name.

I removed it and now I don't face any issue.

This happened also migrating from v8 (no issue) to v9 (with issue).